# How to capture redirects in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, httprequest, action-filter

I have an `ActionFilter` that is successfully capturing page views along with important information from the request. The primary key of this captured entry is then associated with an activity (i.e: Successful Login).

I am trying to now automatically capture Redirects (i.e: `RedirectToAction`) and associate this with the page view as well. I believe this can be done in my `ActionFilter` that is capturing page views, but I am unsure if there is a way to tell from the `OnActionExecuting` context whether or not the GET request is coming from a redirect.

**Is there a way to tell from an `HttpRequest` / `ActionExecutingContext`(or `ActionExecutedContext`) whether or not the page is coming from a redirect?**

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the Referrer header? Other than that, the only other thing I can think of would be to write a cookie into the response and hope the client sends the cookie back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` returns a `RedirectToRouteResult`

In the `OnActionExecuted` method of your filter -

```
if (filterContext.Result is RedirectResult)
{
    // It was a RedirectResult
    var result = filterContext.Result as RedirectResult;
    var url = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(result.Url, filterContext.HttpContext);
}
else if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
{
    // It was a RedirectToRouteResult
    var result = filterContext.Result as RedirectToRouteResult;
    var url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(result.RouteName, null, null, result.RouteValues, RouteTable.Routes, filterContext.RequestContext, false);
}
```